# CSS allow before/after element out of div when parent element has overflow

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I would like my before or after element to be displayed outside the div. Note that this parent div must be a scroll element with overflow auto or scroll, however the out of the div function disables it.

It should look like on the right side, but with scroll function:

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.of {
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

p::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -16px;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  background: green;
  width: 2.313rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="parent of">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused, you want the right side to mirror the left side?

Comment: i want my before/after element to go out of parent, if this parent has an overflow value of scroll or auto (scrollable).

The part on the left is just to show that the overflow function prevents this.

The right side should represent that it can go out of without overflow from the parent

Comment: What is happening on the right hand image is that everything is overflowing (including the text - you just can't see it because it's white on a white background). Could you explain more what you actually want? Is all the p element to be in the overflow or only the green line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make both `parent divs` scrollable you can set `overflow: auto;` on the parent.

I changed your `::after` to `::before` so that it aligned with your text, and not next to it. Then you can change your absolute positioning to `position: fixed;` to make it look like the right side but still have the scrolling ability.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
  border-left: 20px solid #fff;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-left: -23px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -10px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding-left: 10px
}

p::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  background: green;
  width: 2.5rem;
  left: -1px;
  top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="parent">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div

</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps the green lines should stay scrollable?

Comment: @Azu Judging by what the OP said - **"It should look like on the right side, but with scroll function"** that is not the result he wanted. That result is attained easily by setting `overflow: auto;` on the parent.

Comment: i would like the green line to be able to peek out of the div, also i want it to be "sticky" to the text (so also scrollable like @Azu said it already)

Comment: @Kuqs see the adjusted solution.

Comment: So i come with the solution already to my result however i ask myself whether there is not perhaps even something simpler than with padding/margin to work in each case with the parent and their childs. What I wonder is why the overflow property restricts this function so much

Answer (score 0):

I changes and added below css :

```css
.parent {
   border-left: 20px solid #fff;
   padding-left: 20px;
   margin-left: -23px;
   background-clip: content-box;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
p {
   margin-left: -20px;
   background-clip: content-box;
   padding-left: 20px
}
p::before {
   position: absolute;
   left: -0px;
}
```

Final code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
   border-left:20px solid #fff;
  padding-left:20px;
  margin-left:-23px;
    background-clip: content-box;
overflow-x:hidden;
}


p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin-left:-20px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding-left:20px
}

p::before {
  position:  absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  background: green;
  width: 2.313rem;
  left:-0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="parent">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p> <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p> <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: that's about the result i'm looking for, but is it possible to do it that way without moving the text?

Comment: @Kuqs
if i don't move the text then where will be the green bar will show? it will overlap on the left side element.